# mocking api call in vuex action

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuex

I have a vuex store with an action.

```
//actions.js
import api from '@/api.js'

export default {
  getAllProducts ({commit}) {
    // call the api and return a promise with the products

    api.fetchAllProducts().then((products) => {
        commit('getAllProducts', products)
    })  
}
```

Now to test it!

```
// actions.spec.js
import actions from './actions.js'
import api from './api.js'

describe('shop actions', () => {

  it('calls api and fetches products', () => {
    let state = {items: []}
    let commit = sinon.spy()
    let stub = sinon.stub(api, 'fetchAllProducts')
    stub.resolves('a product')

    actions.getAllProducts({commit, state})

    expect(commit.args).to.deep.equal([
        ['SET_ALL_PRODUCTS', 'a product']
    ])  
  })
})
```

This is my attempt so far. It doesn't work for a few reasons.

1. The sinon stub on the api function will not also stub the imported api on actions.js.
2. The api function returns a promise, so the test instead of waiting for it to resolve just returns the assertion, so commit.args will always be [ ]

Any advice on how I could test the vuex action. I think the main difficulty is in stubbing the api module, and I'm quite stuck. Any advice is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

The action `getAllProducts` should return the promise.

```
getAllProducts ({ commit }) {
  return api.fetchAllProducts().then((products) => {
    commit('SET_ALL_PRODUCTS', products)
  })
}
```

Then your test code should be like this:

```
describe('shop actions', () => {
 it('calls api and fetches products', done => {
   let state = {items: []}
   let commit = sinon.spy()
   let stub = sinon.stub(api, 'fetchAllProducts')
   stub.resolves('a product')

   actions.getAllProducts({commit, state}).then(() => {
     expect(commit.args).to.deep.equal([
       ['SET_ALL_PRODUCTS', 'a product']
     ])
     done()
    })
   stub.restore()
   })
})
```

Also, we can use async/await if you are not returning promise from the action.

```
 it('calls api and fetches products', async () => {
   let state = {items: []}
   let commit = sinon.spy()
   let stub = sinon.stub(api, 'fetchAllProducts')
   stub.resolves('a product')

   await actions.getAllProducts({commit, state})
   expect(commit.args).to.deep.equal([
       ['SET_ALL_PRODUCTS', 'a product']
     ])
   stub.restore()
 })
```